# A misunderstanding regarding Shilov's Linear Algebra on bases.

Tags: linear-algebra

> I am reading Shilov's Linear Algebra. Here:

[image]

> I am confused precisely here:

[image]

> How is it possible that $(9)$ form a basis for $P+Q$? I understand that we can use that vectors to find a basis for $P+Q$ is this what he meant? What is confusing to me is that it seems the intersection would contribute with some vectors to the actual dimension of $P+Q$ in a way that the "dimension" of $P+Q$ would be bigger than the actual dimension of $P+Q$.

---

> Perhaps my confusion stems from a previous section of the book:

[image]

> I got a little bit surprised with this because I assumed that the maximum number of linearly independent vectors in $L$ would be the dimension of $L$, but we can find two sets of linearly independent vectors both with the same number of vectors than the dimension of $L$ and they would all be linearly independent, which seems to mean that we can have more linearly independent vectors than the dimension of $L$. Sorry, I am extremely confused.

Comment: Perhaps what is confusing me is the following: Suppose that $e_1, \dots e_k$ "form a basis" for a space of dimension $j<k$. It doesn't mean that the dimension of the space is $k$, it means only that from these $e_i$'s,we can "group" them in the following way:

$$\overbrace {a_1e_1 + a_2e_2}^{f_1}  \overbrace{+\dots+}^{ \dots }  \overbrace{a_{n-1}e_{n-1} + a_ne_n}^{f_j} $$

In a way that for any such "grouping", we can find a basis $f_1,\dots , f_j$.